# ColdFusion 10 with IIS 8 on server 2012, does tomcat need to be installed separately?

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, iis-8

I have ColdFusion 10 setup on Windows Server 2012 with IIS8. My isapi_redirect.log tells me

```
Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port
```

I have setup the tomcat connector in IIS and checked it all a hundred times. Do I need to install tomcat separately as a service or is ColdFusion meant to be running the tomcat service? If ColdFusion is meant to be running it, is there some way to start it manually?

I have checked netstat and tried telneting into the tomcat port. It's definitely not running.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a port conflict issue. You can check the Event Viewer logs. Try the following:-

1. Stop ColdFusion service
2. Launch Command prompt as Administrator
3. Browse to cf_root\cfusion\bin and run the following command coldfusion.exe -start -console
4. Try to access the CF admin, once the services are started.

Open the server.xml file at C:\ColdFusion10\\runtime\conf and check the Connector port & shutdown port. Use `netstat –ano` to get the list of ports and check, if there is a port conflict